# .isHidden property does not reflect changes to the view even after refreshing the view using view.setNeedsDisplay()

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, view

From app delegate after receiving I am passing a static string and refreshing the movieDetailsViewController using set needs Layout, the function and code work properly but the changes don't get reflected in the view.

AppDelegate:-

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let movieDetailsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovieDetailsViewController") as! MovieDetailsViewController




                        if (rootViewController?.isKind(of: MovieDetailsViewController.self))!
                        {
                            if notificationContentType == 1
                            {
                                movieDetailsVC.FROMPAGE = "FROMAPPDELEGATE"
                                movieDetailsVC.view.setNeedsDisplay()
                            }
                        }
```

ViewController:-

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let appDelegate: AppDelegate? = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        appDelegate?.read()

        if FROMPAGE == "FROMAPPDELEGATE"
        {
//                self.updateUI()
            print("Function is Called")
            //print(self.view.frame)
            //self.view.setNeedsDisplay()

            let appDelegate: AppDelegate? = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
            appDelegate?.read()


            var currentreleaseId : Int!
            var currentrentalType : Int!

            currentreleaseId = resultDictionaryFromFCM.value(forKey: "releaseId") as? Int
            let convertedId = String(currentreleaseId)
            currentrentalType = resultDictionaryFromFCM.value(forKey: "rentalType") as? Int
            let elapsedTime = resultDictionaryFromFCM.value(forKey: "elapsedTime") as? Float

            if convertedId == ApiClassStruct.RELEASEID
            {
                let movieStartDate = resultDictionaryFromFCM.value(forKey: "clientStartTime") as? Double
                defaults.set(movieStartDate, forKey: "MOVIE_START_DATE")
                if currentrentalType == 1
                {
                    defaults.set("true", forKey: "isStillPlaying")
                    self.tableViewOutlet.isHidden = true
                    self.seekBarOutlet.isHidden = false


                    let maximumDuration = defaults.integer(forKey: "MAXIMUMDURATION")
                    self.seekBarMaximumDurationLabelOutlet.text = self.convertTime(miliseconds: maximumDuration)
                    self.seekBarOutlet.maximumValue = Float(maximumDuration)

                    let currentDate = NSDate()
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss"
                    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "IST") as TimeZone!
                    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate as Date))
                    let currentDATE = date!.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000

                    let movieStartDate = defaults.value(forKey: "MOVIE_START_DATE") as? Double

                    let difference = currentDATE - movieStartDate!

                    self.seekBarOutlet.setValue(Float(difference), animated: true)
                    let selectedValue = "\(Int(self.seekBarOutlet.value))"
                    let convertedValue = self.convertTime(miliseconds: Int(selectedValue)!)
                    self.seekBarMinimumDurationLabelOutlet.text = convertedValue

                    self.myTimer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

                    print("Play condition ended")
                }
}
```

But the changes dont reflect, stuck in this issue for long.

Comment: what do you mean by the changes not reflecting? did you confirm that `viewDidLoad` was not called before setting `movieDetailsVC.FROMPAGE = "FROMAPPDELEGATE"`?

Comment: it was not called, it gets called after movieDetailsVC.setNeedsDisplay() which I have written in appDelegate. And by changes not reflecting I meant to say if the condition is true seekBarView should be shown but it does not tableView should be hidden but it doesn't get hidden.

Comment: show the code how you present `movieDetailsVC`

Comment: when I receive the notification the condition is checked inside appDelegate and I called setNeedsDisplay() I want to update or say it as I want to refresh the view then and there only without going back and forth.

Comment: `let movieDetailsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovieDetailsViewController") as! MovieDetailsViewController` creates a new object. you are setting things on this new object. if an instance is already presented, it will not be affected.

Comment: ok, then an alternative solution you can help me, please ?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168391/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-smitesh-wadher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let movieDetailsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovieDetailsViewController") as! MovieDetailsViewController
```

Creates a new instance of `MovieDetailsViewController`, and modifies that. If you don't present that instance, no change will be visible. If you already have presented `MovieDetailsViewController` instance, the presented instance will not be affected by it.

I would recommend using notifications to notify `MovieDetailsViewController` to update its UI.

E.g., in app delegate use this to create and post a new notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("movieDetailsUpdateNotif"),
                                object: self, userInfo: nil)
```

And then in `MovieDetailsViewController.viewDidLoad` register to listen to those notifications:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(receiveNotification(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name("movieDetailsUpdateNotif"),
                                           object: nil)
}
```

To clean it up, unregister in `deinit` (just to behave nicely):

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Finally, implement `MovieDetailsViewController.receiveNotification(notification:)` to handle notification:

```
@objc fileprivate func receiveNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    // update UI here, e.g. hide things, show other, etc.
    // this will be called when AppDelegate creates a and posts that notification
}
```